# The first trip to the planet Nars

Tags: mathematics, optimization

MASA have built a rocket to fly to the planet Nars which contains millions of tons of fuel which the Earth has run short of. The planet is 100 light-years away from earth. MASA has enough fuel to travel for 10 light-years. For a solution MASA have created a liquid which can cause the fuel to expand when burnt thus increasing the light-years the ship can travel.

MASAs ship can contain 1000 tons of fuel. 100 tons can take the ship a single light-year. Light years possible to travel = fuel / 100.
The formula MASA has devised, for every ton of it, it will multiply the light-years possible to travel by the tons of liquid squared plus the square root of fuel. So: 
$$X = f/100 * (\ell^2+\sqrt{f}),$$
where $X$ = Lightyears possible to travel, $f$ = fuel in tank and $\ell$ = MASAs formula in tank.

You can put as much liquid and fuel in the tank (not exceeding 1000 tons) as you want.

> Is it possible for MASA to get to the planet Nars?
>   
>   If so what is the minimum fuel and formula required to get there?
>   If not what is the minimum sized tank capacity requires and how much fuel and formula is required?

Comment: @Gamow thanks I have never had a clue how to do that stuff

Comment: Am I calculating this wrong or is any amount of fuel more than 100 tons with the correct amount of formula to get to 1000 tons, possible to get to Nars?

Comment: @Okx Probably I am unsure yself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can do this maximizing the formula given

$max \ \frac{f}{100}\times(\ell^2+\sqrt{f})$

with the constraint;

$\ell+f=1000$

[The solution gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20x%2F100*(y%5E2%2Bsqrt(x))%20where%20x%2By%3D1000)

$f=333.347$

$\ell=666.653$

and $X$ becomes

$X=1,481,542$

so it should be much more than enough :P I am not sure this is intended answer though since it is much more bigger than 1,000.

So how much $\ell$ and $f$ is needed to reach that planet? Which is the reverse optimization;

$min\ \ell+f$

with the constraint;

$ \ \frac{f}{100}\times(\ell^2+\sqrt{f})=100$

So [The result is (according to Wolfram Alpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20x%2By%20where%20x*(y%5E2%2Bsqrt(x))%3D10000)

$f=13.6177$

$\ell=27.0305$

Minimum size capacity will be the sum of these values;

$40.6482$